# Hide non default URL port

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications, web-config, port

How to hide non default  URL port number for IIS and ASP :
example:
**https://myweb.com:4797** - To be > **https://myweb.com**

Writing port number with URL difficult for users and not secure also to show it in the web search bar ?

Comment: Rule of thumb: expose non-default ports, hide default ports.

Comment: Thanks, Already must to expose non don-default ports but want to hide port number in URL link

Comment: Why cannot you use standard port number? Non-standard ports won't give you any extra security benefits, and LOL someone called it "rule of thumb". If you do need extra security protection, that's something you should explore in networking fields (gateway/firewall in front), and has little to do with Windows/IIS any more.